# Is there a way to use pattern matching in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, build, pattern-matching, sbt

I'm trying to play with Scala's PlayFramework and am running into an issue with my build.sbt file. Specifically:

```
Pattern matching in val statements is not supported
```

Which is from the obvious:

```
val env = sys.props.getOrElse("ENV", default = "local") 
val (someVal, otherVal) = env match {
    case "local" => ("x","a")
    case _ => //etc
}
```

Is there a way to use a match statement in the build.sbt file at all? The error says that it's not supported in val statements. Where is it actually supported?

---

Edit:

I've tried adding a method to a build.scala object as well, but even when I use plain if statements I still get the same "Pattern matching in val statements is not supported"

Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ExampleBuild extends Build {

    def getEnvData(env: String) = {
        if(env == "local") {
            ("c","q") 
        } else if (env == "other") {
            ("b","v")
        } else {
            ("x","a")
        }
    }    
}
```

And updated build.sbt:

```
val env = sys.props.getOrElse("ENV", default = "local") 
val (someVar, otherVar) = ExampleBuild.getEnvData(env)
```

But to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not caused by the `match` statement, but from this:

```
val (someVar, otherVar) = ...
```

which is a form of pattern matching (on tuples) not supported by sbt.

Here's a relevant comment from the [`SbtParser` implementation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.7/sxr/sbt/internals/parser/SbtParser.scala.html)

> // Check No val (a,b) = foo *or* val a,b = foo as these are problematic to range positions and the WHOLE architecture.

---

You can work around this limitation by using a case class instead of a tuple.

#### in `Build.scala`

```
case class EnvData(someVar: String, otherVar: String)
```

#### in `build.sbt`

```
val envData = env match {
    case "local" => EnvData("x", "a")
    case _ => //etc
}
```

and then use it like `envData.someVar`, `envData.otherVar` and so on.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, I needed to define the case class in the Build.scala file and not the build.sbt to have it work

Comment: Another option is to continue to use a tuple in build.sbt, then deconstruct it into 2 values, with _1 and _2